# In R, how to predict with svm model in parallel using foreach/snow?

Tags: r, pca, svm, parallel-processing

I'm trying to improve the performance of my R program, which is using an SVM trained on PCAs, by using the foreach and doSNOW packages. I've already trained the models and am now passing my validation set through the PCA model and then the SVM model to get predictions.

Interestingly enough, I was able to successfully use foreach/snow to parallelize the predictions in the PCA model, but I'm getting errors when doing it with the SVM model. I suspect it's an issue of the output data type and properly combining the results, but I'm not sure.

Also worth noting that I'm only using the first 500 principal components. I trained my SVM model the same way.

Note - I generally followed a modified version of these instructions, which had some bugs that I had to fix:
http://www.r-bloggers.com/parallel-r-model-prediction-building-and-analytics/

```
library(zoo)

# run PCA on training data
pr <- prcomp(na.aggregate(sampled_ds), scale=TRUE)

# train svm on first 500 principal components
library(e1071);

model <- svm(pr$x[,1:500], #captures 96% of variance
             y=as.factor(responder), probability=TRUE);

# snow setup
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)
cl<-makeCluster(6) #change the 4 to your number of CPU cores
registerDoSNOW(cl)
num_splits<-6

# generate PCA version of validation set
split_testing<-sort(rank(1:nrow(validation))%%num_splits)
pca_predictions<-foreach(i=0:num_splits-1,
                        .combine=rbind,
                         .packages=c("e1071")) %dopar% {
                           predict(pr,newdata=validation[split_testing==i,])
                         }

# generate SVM preidctions using PCA output
split_testing<-sort(rank(1:nrow(pca_predictions))%%num_splits)

output <- foreach(i=0:num_splits-1,
                         .combine=rbind,.packages=c("e1071")) %dopar% {
                           predict(model,newdata=pca_predictions[split_testing==i,1:500], probability=TRUE)
                         }
```

I get the following error on the last step:

```
Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [0]"
In addition: Warning message:
In fun(result.2, result.3, result.4, result.5, result.6, result.7) :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
I tried na.aggregate to get rid of NAs first, in case that was causing any problems. I also tried to debug by manually simulating what foreach does (I thought) like so:

```
tst1 <- predict(model,newdata=pca_predictions[split_testing==0,1:500], probability=TRUE)
tst2 <- predict(model,newdata=pca_predictions[split_testing==1,1:500], probability=TRUE)
rbind(tst1,tst2)
```

I only get a warning, not the error I got with foreach:

```
Warning message:
In rbind(tst1, tst2) :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

Comment: Typically when I get an error like that it means I accidentally overwrote something with `<NA>`s, or `NULL`, or the wrong data structure. Did you try running `traceback()` after the error? If there's an issue with the data types that tends to help uncover it. Particularly since a lot of non-`base` R functions have proprietary, list-like classes for their return structures. Try running `str` on `pca_predictions` and make sure it's the right data type. That, or `rbind` is failing (based on the error) in which case, again, you might be returning something odd. Also nice username.

Comment: Also did you try making sure `%%` is giving you even splits? You might just be off by a row here and there.

Comment: I don't think %% is an issue, as the pca version of this worked fine. I"ll give it another look though. I thought it might be NAs in my dataset given your other comment so I did na.aggregate on the validation set before passing it in, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: I've given up on this. I wasn't able to find any way to get the same error that foreach was giving using a non-parallel methodology to help debug. I'm running fully sequentially now as I don't have any more time to spend trying to speed it up.